# Circuit Lower bound for $EXP^{NP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, lower-bounds, circuits

By Burhman, Fortnow and Thierauf result [Paper Link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e840/7aadee8f59a5773e899c6360aa3241ac8bf0.pdf), we know that $MA_{EXP} \not\subset P/poly$.

Also, we know that $MA \subseteq P^{NP}$ (or $\Delta_{2}^{P}$ in some literatures).

By using the padding technique, we can conclude from this $MA_{EXP} \subseteq EXP^{NP} \not\subset P/poly$ and hence yielding a circuit lower bound for $EXP^{NP}$.

What is wrong with this argument?

Comment: We don't know that $MA\subseteq P^{NP}$.

Comment: @Ariel I found this on Fortnow blog [Link: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2002/12/complexity-class-of-week-ma.html ]: MA is also contained in many of the same classes BPP is contained in, including $S_2^P$ (See 6th Paragraph)

Comment: This is a different class, see [zoo entry](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#s2p)

Comment: @Ariel Yes. Got it. I wrongly interpreted $S_{2}^{P}$ same as $\Delta_{2}^{P}$. Thanks for the clarification.